# HTML5 / Jquery dropbox param

Tags: jquery, json

I am really new to JSON - it seems an excellent language to learn :)

I have recently started using the following script: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

I have edited the PHP file to what I like but my problem is I need a perimeter to be sent when a file is uploaded. I need it to send the folder ID so I know which location to shove the file (by adding into a database and recalling he data later).

I'm not sure how to pass this parimiter on once I drop a file and was wondering if someone could explain how?

Thanks you for any help received.

Kind regards

Andrew

Comment: You need to send the folder ID from the server to the client, or from the client to the server? In either case, we'll need to see the code the generates the folder ID as well.

Comment: Well its easy getting the Folder ID where the uploader is it's just I don't know how to pass this on whilst the file is uploading - I can then use this parimiter in the PHP upload file to insert it into the database as well as add the file.

Comment: so client -> PHP upload file -> (add to database - this I can do) just need to post the parimiter so I can collect it

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the code as follows:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
    //do logic to generate folder ID
    exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!', $folder_id);
}
```

Then modify the `exit_status()` function:

```
function exit_status($str, $folder_id){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str, 'folder_id' => $folder_id));
    exit;
}
```

then, modify the `uploadFinished` function of the `dropbox.filedrop` method:

```
uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
    $.data(file).addClass('done');
    // response is the JSON object that post_file.php returns
    response.folder_id now contains the $folder_id generated on the server   
}
```